# What do we call the brown-colored paper found in old books?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, books

I want to know what that brown and slightly roughly-textured paper is called, or whether there even is a word for it.

Comment: Are you looking for *parchment paper?*

Comment: related: [what is the origin of the verb "foxed"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/614478/what-is-the-origin-of-the-verb-foxed-in-reference-to-book-condition)

Answer (score 4):

If the brown bits are spots, it would be called *[foxing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/foxing):-*

> brownish spots on old paper

Comment: +1. Beyond "spotted", even if then whole (every) page is brown, it's still *foxing*: "the whole page is *foxed*","my goodness, the entire volume is *foxed*".  For the OP, the pages are brown for the same reason a cut apple turns brown, or a banana turns brown, or a iron gate turns brown (or a silver coin turns *black*): *foxing* is a synonym for *oxidation*.

Answer (score 3):

parchment paper is old writing paper, there's also blotting paper, which is like parchment paper but went under the parchment to absorb excess ink.

You can call it parchment paper or just parchment, both are correct.

Comment: *Parchment* is a predecessor of modern paper: *parchment-like paper* may well be what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use any of the following: "Antique Paper", "Old Paper", or if you want it technical and associate it with design, you can use "Sepia Grunge Texture". Hope that helps..